# Why are hard links limited to their own machine?

Tags: file, filesystems

Regarding file systems, I have read that hard links cannot be used across different machines but I am having trouble understanding why. Also, what makes symbolic links able to be used across different machines?

Thank you

Comment: Hardlinks are more limited than that: because they "link" to an *internal filesytem detail* (eg. an inode) they can only be used within the *same filesystem*.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is laid well here:http://linuxgazette.net/105/pitcher.html

So to make a long story short hardlinks use inodes of their file system so moving it would destroy its refrence on the filesystem. I would read the link for better info tho.